# reassigning Global variables in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am new to shell scripting and I need some help on the following problem:

I have script. It has a global variable defined as follows:

```
ARCHIVE_USER=user1
```

Then, in a method, I am changing the values for these variables:

```
test_function(){

  ARCHIVE_USER=user2
  test_function2()
}

test_function2(){
  echo ARCHIVE_USER
}
```

I want `test_function2` to print "user2" instead of "user1" because in the `test_function` I have renamed the variable value to "user2", but when I run it, it is always giving me "user1" as the output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: echo $ARCHIVE_USER should be better in your test_function2(). Or you can use "export" to set the to the entire environment. Example : export ARCHIVE_USER=user1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script works as you expect it should, i.e. it prints "B".

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

TEST=A

test_a()
{ 
    TEST=B
    test_b
}

test_b()
{
    echo $TEST
}

test_a
```

So, my question to you is how are you calling your test_function()?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i have given a sample script here, in my original script, before asigning value B to TEST variable, test_b is called by some other function. that has making the problem. your answer helped me to nail down the issue. thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2):

You should define those function in the same environment.

If you put them in different scripts, and run them by `/path/to/script_1.sh` and `/path/to/script_2`. They will not affect each other. Because they run in different environment.

You should read more about `subshell/subprocess`.